# Get parent section of a clicked element

Tags: javascript

How can I know which section the element `<p\>` I am clicking on belongs to? (vanilla js)

```html
<div id="container">
    <section>
        <h3>SECTION 1</h3>
        <div>
            <p>AAA</p>
            <p>BBB</p>
            <p>CCC</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>SECTION 2</h3>
        <div>
            <p>DDD</p>
            <p>EEE</p>
            <p>FFF</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

```
document.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    if (e.target.nodeName == 'P') {
        //
        //
    }
})
```

With Jquery I can do something like:

```
$(document).on("click","section:last-child>div>p",function(){
```

Thanks!

Comment: `e.target.closest('section')`, but you need to check also, that the click is on a `p`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) on [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target):

```js
document.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  console.clear(); // clear the console log
  if(e.target.nodeName == 'P') {
    var sec = e.target.closest('section');
    console.log(sec.textContent);
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section>
      <h3>SECTION 1</h3>
      <div>
          <p>AAA</p>
          <p>BBB</p>
          <p>CCC</p>
      </div>
  </section>
  <section>
      <h3>SECTION 2</h3>
      <div>
          <p>DDD</p>
          <p>EEE</p>
          <p>FFF</p>
      </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go to parent most element of `h3` and `div` and get the `textContent` of the `h3` to get the section name.

```js
const allPara = document.querySelectorAll("p");

allPara.forEach(para => {
  para.addEventListener("click", e => {
    const sectionElement = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
    const sectionName = sectionElement.children[0].textContent;
    console.log(sectionName);
  })
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section>
    <h3>SECTION 1</h3>
    <div>
      <p>AAA</p>
      <p>BBB</p>
      <p>CCC</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>SECTION 2</h3>
    <div>
      <p>DDD</p>
      <p>EEE</p>
      <p>FFF</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

But it would be easy if you add [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on section to identify the `section`.

```js
const allPara = document.querySelectorAll("p");

allPara.forEach(para => {
  para.addEventListener("click", e => {
    const sectionElement = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
    const sectionName = sectionElement.dataset.section;
    console.log( sectionName );
  })
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section data-section="section 1">
    <h3>SECTION 1</h3>
    <div>
      <p>AAA</p>
      <p>BBB</p>
      <p>CCC</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section data-section="section 2">
    <h3>SECTION 2</h3>
    <div>
      <p>DDD</p>
      <p>EEE</p>
      <p>FFF</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) to find if the element is a `p`. Then use [`Element.closes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to find the `section`:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if(!target.matches('p')) return; // use matches to check if p was clicked

  const section = target.closest('section'); // find the closest section
  
  if(!section) return;
  
  const header = section.querySelector('h3'); // find the header
  
  console.log(header.innerText);
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section>
    <h3>SECTION 1</h3>
    <div>
      <p>AAA</p>
      <p>BBB</p>
      <p>CCC</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>SECTION 2</h3>
    <div>
      <p>DDD</p>
      <p>EEE</p>
      <p>FFF</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to get all the matching elements, then you can use `===` operator to check if the element you clicked on is equal to a matching element

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const selector = "section:last-child>div>p";
    const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    const matchSelector = Array.from(nodes ).some(el => el == e.target);
    
    if (matchSelector) {
      // do something
      console.log("do something");
    }

});
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <section>
        <h3>SECTION 1</h3>
        <div>
            <p>AAA</p>
            <p>BBB</p>
            <p>CCC</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>SECTION 2</h3>
        <div>
            <p>DDD</p>
            <p>EEE</p>
            <p>FFF</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```